# Can't change hostname and key for Tor hidden service

Tags: onion-routing

I've generated private key and hostname to my onion domain using [scallion](https://github.com/lachesis/scallion), and I have tried to copy and paste it into the hidden service directory, to the "hostname" and "privatekey" files, but wheb I tried to start tor it showed me an error. scallion generated for me 13 keys and domains, but none of them worked. I copied the hostname and got down a line, and I entered the private key including "----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----" and the same but to the end "end rsa...", but it didn't work. Does anybody ever tried host hidden service on windows and change hostname? what am 
I doing wrong?

(tor configure to the right folder directory)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I tried to change onion domain to one I have generated using scallion, and when I restarted TOR it returned error.

Comment: But you need to say what the error is!

Comment: Copy that error message here but replace the onion hostnames with Xxxxx and Yyyyyy for an old and a new one

Answer (score 1):

You’re not providing any useful information here. However, I’ll take a guess at what your problem might be:

Tor is very particular about file permissions. I’m guessing that you didn’t change file ownership to the tor service’s user account, or that you didn’t change the file permissions to read-only for the tor account and no access to any other user account.